# "Enrolled users" tab in Course administration is not displaying

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

Hi i am newbie to moodle. Please can anyone help me, how to display the "enrolled users" tab in course administration. By default the enrolled users tab is not displaying in course administration.I am using moodle 2.8 version. I need to get the enrolled users tab as shown in the image. Image is been attached herewith [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGzQz.png)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably permissions.

I think the code to display the menu node is in `lib/enrollib.php` in `function enrol_add_course_navigation`. Look for `get_string('enrolledusers', 'enrol')`

Just before that it has `has_capability('moodle/course:enrolreview', $coursecontext)`

Check that the user you are logged in as, has the the permission `moodle/course:enrolreview`. You will need to log in as admin then go to site admin -> users -> permissions -> capability overview and search for `moodle/course:enrolreview`

Answer (score 1):

By default, enrolled users tab shows in the course administration when we install Moodle. And there is no way to hide/ show this tab/link.

May be there is some issue raised during installation of Moodle.